bpf_probe_write_user helper function correct usage
I wanted to know if the below bpf program is a correct one to modify a argument of __x64_sys_sysinfo system call using bpf_probe_write_user() helper function in eBPF?
#define __TARGET_ARCH_x86
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_tracing.h>
#include <linux/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/pci_regs.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#ifndef _LINUX_SYSINFO_H
#define _LINUX_SYSINFO_H

#define SI_LOAD_SHIFT   16
struct sysinfo {
    __kernel_long_t uptime;     /* Seconds since boot */
    __kernel_ulong_t loads[3];  /* 1, 5, and 15 minute load averages */
    __kernel_ulong_t totalram;  /* Total usable main memory size */
    __kernel_ulong_t freeram;   /* Available memory size */
    __kernel_ulong_t sharedram; /* Amount of shared memory */
    __kernel_ulong_t bufferram; /* Memory used by buffers */
    __kernel_ulong_t totalswap; /* Total swap space size */
    __kernel_ulong_t freeswap;  /* swap space still available */
    __u16 procs;            /* Number of current processes */
    __u16 pad;          /* Explicit padding for m68k */
    __kernel_ulong_t totalhigh; /* Total high memory size */
    __kernel_ulong_t freehigh;  /* Available high memory size */
    __u32 mem_unit;         /* Memory unit size in bytes */
    char _f[20-2*sizeof(__kernel_ulong_t)-sizeof(__u32)];   /* Padding: libc5 uses this.. */
};

#endif

SEC("kprobe/__x64_sys_sysinfo")
int inject_error(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
    struct sysinfo *user_info_ptr = (struct sysinfo *)PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx);

    __kernel_ulong_t fake_totalram = -10000000007;

    bpf_probe_write_user(&user_info_ptr->totalram, &fake_totalram, sizeof(fake_totalram));

    bpf_printk("Successfully modified sysinfo buffer in userspace\n");
    return 0;
}

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "GPL";

Although, this bpf program is getting compiled, loaded and attached successfully but the value of totalram is not getting over-ridden.
I expected the parameter totalram, to get over-ridden by the value of -10000000007.
